# Unable to create Database in SQL Server using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

```
$primaryReplica = $configFile.Config.PrimaryReplica
$Database = $configFile.Config.DatabaseName
$SqlServer = $configFile.Config.ServerName

$machineName = gc env:computername

if ($machineName -eq $primaryReplica)
{
    Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking

    cd "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$SqlServer\Default\Databases"
    $DatabaseInstance = Get-Item "$Database" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($DatabaseInstance -eq $null)
    {
        # Create DB
        $DatabaseInstance = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database
        $DatabaseInstance.Parent = Get-Item "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$SqlServer\Default"
        $DatabaseInstance.Name = $Database
        $DatabaseInstance.RecoveryModel = "Full"
        $DatabaseInstance.Create()
    }
```

I wish to create database in SQL Server using PowerShell script.
The above code is generating the following error:

> Exception setting "Parent": "Cannot convert the "[PAAROR]" value of type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server"."

Comment: can you try passing `"PAAROR"` instead of `"[PAAROR]"`?

Comment: I have tried that only

Answer (score 0):

To isolate the problem, start by verifying a [Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx) object can be instantiated using the `$SqlServer` instance name. Then proceed to database creation:

```
$primaryReplica = $configFile.Config.PrimaryReplica
$Database = $configFile.Config.DatabaseName
$SqlServer = $configFile.Config.ServerName
...
    if ($DatabaseInstance -eq $null)
    {
        # Create DB
        $SqlServerInstance = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server $SqlServer
        $DatabaseInstance = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO.Database($SqlServerInstance, $Database)
        $DatabaseInstance.Create()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're getting conflicting types from different assemblies. Here's what I see on my system:

```
> (get-item "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$server").GetType().Assembly.Location
```

> C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

```
> [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server].Assembly.Location
```

> C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

`sqlps` is giving me types from SQL Server 2014, but resolving the type directly is giving me types from SQL Server 2016. This is because both are loaded when you import `sqlps`, which is... unfortunate.

If you are using the new modules from SQL Server 2016 onwards, you should be importing `SqlServer` instead (and then you can leave out `-DisableNameChecking` as well). If you must use `sqlps` for backwards compatibility, I'm not sure what the proper solution is. As an incredibly ugly workaround, you can specify the type name explicitly as `[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database, Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91]`, but obviously this breaks if the provider isn't actually of this version.

Comment: (get-item "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$server").GetType().Assembly.Location command gives C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\sqlps\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider.dll and [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server].Assembly.Location gives C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

Comment: what changes do I need to make now